# Velocity Liferay Issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, liferay, liferay-6, velocity, liferay-velocity

I'm running Liferay 6.2 GA2. 
Created a Web Content with a dummy Structure and Template with the following source.

```
#set($layoutServiceUtil = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutService"))
#set($topPublicLayouts = $layoutServiceUtil.getLayouts($groupId,true))
#set($viewCountExpName = 'viewCount')
#set($viewCount = ${topPublicLayouts.get(0).getExpandoBridge().getAttribute($viewCountExpName)})
Works in Chrome-${topPublicLayouts.get(0).getExpandoBridge().getAttribute($viewCountExpName)}-
-${topPublicLayouts.get(0).getNameCurrentValue()}-
--${viewCount}--
```

Created the custom attribute, removed the Velocity restrictions from the portal-ext.properties.

The above code works in Chrome but doesn't work in IE.

Response in Chrome:

> Works in Chrome-1617- -Home- --1617--

Response in IE (8,9,10 & 11):

> Works in
>   Chrome-${topPublicLayouts.get(0).getExpandoBridge().getAttribute($viewCountExpName)}-
>   -Home- --${viewCount}--

Debug on the Velocity Packages give me the below error logs only for IE:

```
17:41:45,687 DEBUG [RuntimePageImpl-6][velocity:155] Null reference [template '10257#10297#12641', line 5, column 17] : ${topPublicLayouts.get(0).getExpandoBridge().getAttribute($viewCountExpName)} cannot be resolved.
17:41:45,688 DEBUG [RuntimePageImpl-6][velocity:155] Null reference [template '10257#10297#12641', line 7, column 3] : ${viewCount} cannot be resolved.
```

How can I get the `$viewCount` value working in IE browser.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a 'browser caching' issue?

Comment: Nope. Cleared cache. Browser temp files. Tested in 5 different machines. All the other changes in the script are reflected properly.

Comment: And even in the server logs, the error appears only when I refresh IE Page